# Does android:theme in appcompat 22.1.0 only work for Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

In the following layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

`TextView` is not using themed text colors on pre-L devices. If I move this theme declaration to TextView it works on all devices. Chris Banes in his article wrote:

> In 22.1.0 we now have expanded that functionality so that you can set
>   a theme on any view in your layouts.
>   https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/

So I'm confused, bug?

**EDIT**:

I looked into Toolbar and Toolbar also seems to have this issue—the following layout doesn't work as intended too:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="#@#@SDAG"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Link that article here.

Comment: I've add it link to article

Comment: maybe post your theme here to show how you set it.

Comment: Why it would matter? I use light app compat with custom colors, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found source of the problem. I was directly adding items to R.id.content. Like `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_activity, findViewById(R.id.content);` instead of using `setContentView` method that does all the magic stuff. Unfortunately in documentation there is no word that you must use `setContentXXX` method.

Answer (score -1):

With new version (v22.1) of support lib your activity should extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` you used to extend so far.

Here's Google devs' post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: It should and I do that, although it doesn't matter since deprecated one extends the valid one.